# Game script for upgrading

Tags: windows, python, game

So I am playing an old MMORPG game. I would really like to create a simple script to execute a few clicks with the mouse and a few button presses. I tried using autoit and autohotkey but that didn't help me because not every button is in the same place every time. I searched the Internet and found that most people use opencv with python. I couldn't install opencv properly so if someone could help me install it correctly or recommend me an alternative. I am using a windows 10 64 bits system.